# My write to console not visible on Eclipse console any more

Tags: java, android, libgdx, console, eclipse-luna

I'm running Eclipse Luna, 4.4.2. Recently I've run some updates (Help / Check for updates) and since then everything is messed up. I.e. my templates are lost and some default which I can't even delete are added ?!? Even worst, when I'm writing to console with:

```
System.out.println("Some text");
```

output is not visible in console?!? Like there are many different consoles there: Android, Robo VM, DDMS, Java Stack Trace... but none of them is getting my output?!?

I'm really surprised that Eclipse could get update so destructible. What console should I use now, and why is printing to console not working any more?

Comment: Have you tried: `Window -> Show View` find `Console` there

Comment: Console tab is already visible and it can show one of many console types. But none of them is displaying content that I output with System.out.println when I execute android app.With windows app it's working well.